# Android Studio error cursor hover tooltip/suggestion disappears instantly

Tags: windows-10, android-studio, tooltip

I have had this issue for a while but just ignored it by viewing Dart Analysis but basically when coding in Android Studio, if I come across a code error, mistake etc. when I hover over the error, usually a tooltip should popup explaining the issue which it does but then it disappears instantly not allowing me to read the issue. If I move my cursor away and over the error it repeats the same process.

I have looked at the error and tooltip settings but nothing fixes the issue. Currently using latest android Studio build. Hovering over tabs, icons etc. allows me to read descriptions, info of said action but not errors.

Does anyone know of a fix apart from trying to reinstall Android Studio?
I fear that might be the case.

Thanks.

Comment: Dis you fix it? same here

Comment: Unfortunately not but I got it down to it being my laptop having an issue with Windows 10 and the SSD being faulty. Replacing the SSD fixed the issue but ultimately I had to get a new PC anyway. Probably not the answer you were looking for but as was stated to me on many forums and posts, it could just be a bug with the latest version of Android Studio/Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok FYI I have reinstall Android Studio and pb is gone now

Comment: Downgraded to previous version